# Data-carousel on flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, flexslider

I have made a carousel with flexslider, however I had a problem. I have more than 10 carousels on the page. Every carousel has his own classes.

This is the html:

```
<div class="box-product-details hide" data-carousel="1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="product-carousel">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="../images/product-detail.jpg" height="338" width="430" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="../images/product-detail.jpg" height="338" width="430" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="../images/product-detail.jpg" height="338" width="430" alt="" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /product-carousel -->
    </div><!-- /container -->
</div><!-- /box-product-details -->
<div class="box-product-details hide" data-carousel="2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="product-carousel">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="../images/product-detail.jpg" height="338" width="430" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="../images/product-detail.jpg" height="338" width="430" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="../images/product-detail.jpg" height="338" width="430" alt="" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /product-carousel -->
    </div><!-- /container -->
</div><!-- /box-product-details -->
```

The only difference is the data carousel attribute on the box product div.

**Now my question**
How can I start carousels all apart. With the carousel attribute on the box product. How can i start this carousels apart. Here is my javascript.

```
$('.product-carousel').flexslider({
     namespace: "carousel-",
     animation: 'fade',
     selector: 'ul > li',
 });
```

Comment: I think you should give unique ID to every product-carousel you have and start them using ID selector $('#idnumber').flexslider()

Answer (score 0):

if you can do:

```
$('.product-carousel').each(function() {
  var sliderCarousel = $(this).closest('.box-product-details').data('carousel');
  $(this).flexslider({
    // flexslider options and you can use sliderCarousel in here.
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('.box-product-details[data-carousel="2"]').flexslider({
     namespace: "carousel-",
     animation: 'fade',
     selector: 'ul > li',
 });
```

or if is already instanciated

```
$('.box-product-details[data-carousel="2"]').play() ;
```

Doc for html 5 data attributes :

http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: How can I go walking through the differtent data-carousels?

Comment: $('.box-product-details').length gives you number of carousel